# Rails and Ruby date calculation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

controller action:

```
@days = (@date_start - Date.today)
```

rendering `<%= @days %>` returns

```
2/1
```

The first digit is correct.  How is the rest being generated and what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to docs:](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D)

> d - other → date or rational
>
> Returns the difference between the two dates if the other is a date object. If the other is a numeric value, returns a date object pointing other days before self. If the other is flonum, assumes its precision is at most nanosecond.

So your `(2/1)` is a `Rational` number. You can check it with `@days.class`.

If your `@date_start` is also `Date` object - you can convert `@days` to `Integer` to get difference in days with `@days.to_i` without information loss since difference between `Date`s will always be `(n/1)`

But in general, method returns `Rational`, because you can also subtract `DateTime` objects(specifying not only date, but also time), like this:

```
DateTime.new(2001,2,3) - DateTime.new(2001,2,2,12)
# 03 Feb 2001 00:00:00 - 02 Feb 2001 12:00:00
# => (1/2)
```

And in this case only half of the day is between `03 Feb 2001 00:00:00` and `02 Feb 2001 12:00:00`, thus it returns `(1/2)`.

Comment: Brilliant!  It also explains the fundamental logic of how this comes about.